# Cannot get Basic HTTP Authentication to work using Restlet 2.1

Tags: java, rest, authentication, basic-authentication, restlet

I'm trying to implement basic HTTP authentication using Restlet 2.1, and I just can't get it to work .. ! I'm using a `ChallengeAuthenticator` to setup Basic HTTP authentication. I have just one URI `\test`, for which I'm trying to get authentication working.

I build my code, then run it as a Web Application and then browse to `http://localhost:8888/test` to see if I get a prompt for a username/password, but I don't get any. I just get a blank screen.

Also when I browse to `http://localhost:8888/test`, I get the following written in Eclipse's Console:

```
WARNING: A response with a 200 (Ok) status should have an entity. Make sure that resource "http://localhost:8888/test" returns one or sets the status to 204 (No content).
```

When when I browse to `http://user:password@localhost:8888/test`, the result is exactly the same.

**The HTTP headers (from Chrome) are as follows:**

Request:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6
```

Response (no mention of Basic authentication):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 11:21:05 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Development/1.0
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

**Here is the Java code:**

```
package com.poc.hw7;

import org.restlet.*;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;
import org.restlet.data.Cookie;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;
import org.restlet.security.*;
import org.restlet.util.Series;

public class AuthTestApp extends Application {

    private ChallengeAuthenticator authenticator;

    private ChallengeAuthenticator createAuthenticator() {
        Context context = getContext();
        boolean optional = false;
        ChallengeScheme challengeScheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
        String realm = "Example site";

        MapVerifier verifier = new MapVerifier();
        verifier.getLocalSecrets().put("user", "password".toCharArray());

        ChallengeAuthenticator auth = new ChallengeAuthenticator(context, optional, challengeScheme, realm, verifier) {
            @Override
            protected boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
                if (request.getChallengeResponse() == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return super.authenticate(request, response);
                }
            }
        };
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        this.authenticator = createAuthenticator();

        Restlet hw_restlet = new Restlet(getContext())
        {
        public void handle(Request request, Response response)
            {
            String message = "Hello World!";
            response.setEntity(message,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            }
        };

        Router router = new Router();
        router.attach("/test", hw_restlet);
        authenticator.setNext(router);
        return authenticator;
    }

    public boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
        if (!request.getClientInfo().isAuthenticated()) {
            authenticator.challenge(response, false);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here is the web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Restlet URI Rewrite</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.poc.hw7.AuthTestApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can someone please tell me how to get basic HTTP authentication working ?

Answer (score 0):

Your response was a 200 code, which means your server never asked for one. You would need to send a 401 response. For most web browsers, this will automatically pop up the basic-auth box for a username and password.

As for why this is happening... it's hard to say. `restlet` looks very... bad. There are easier frameworks to work with, where you can just annotate a function to listen to a certain URI and/or request method.